# Abstract method in non-abstract class?

Tags: android

I'm slightly confused here.
While I was reading the API Documentation of some Android's classes, I found out that [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) class contains an abstract method

`abstract void drawText(Canvas c, int start, int end, float x, float y, Paint p)`

while `SpannableStringBuilder` is a non-abstract class.

As I know , a non-abstract class can not contain an abstract method, and can not be instantiated. (SpannableStringBuilder can be instantiated as well)
So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

All of what you said is true.

That is a documentation bug. The method is not abstract.

Source code

```
 /**
 * Don't call this yourself -- exists for Canvas to use internally.
 * {@hide}
 */
public void drawText(Canvas c, int start, int end,
                     float x, float y, Paint p) {
    checkRange("drawText", start, end);

    if (end <= mGapStart) {
[...]
```